# How to use newsecret in capacitor-community/sqlite when creating connection

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, encryption, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

In my Ionic 5 app, I am using the [capacitor-community/sqlite](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite) plugin. To create and encrypt a database. I am doing the following as per documentation.

```
await this.sqlite.createConnection('database1', false, "no-encryption", 1);
await this.sqlite.createConnection('database1', true, "encryption", 1);
await this.sqlite.createConnection('database1', true, "secret", 1);
```

> - the mode "encryption" is to be used when you have an already existing database non encrypted and you want to encrypt it.
> - the mode "secret" is to be used when you want to open an encrypted database.
> - the mode "newsecret" is to be used when you want to change the secret    of an encrypted database with the newsecret.

A `secret` and `newsecret` is maintained in the configuration file as an encryption password.  When I create the connection with the `secret` it works fine but I am unable to use the `newsecret`.

```
await this.sqlite.createConnection('database1', true, "newsecret", 1);
```

The above code is supposed to change my connection secret but it's not working. When I run this code it executes with no error but when I run `await this.db.open();`, it fails with error `"Open command failed: Failed in openOrCreateDatabase Wrong Secret"`. I didn't find the correct way to implement this method in the official documentations.

Comment: which version of the plugin are you using? because the docs say: "Since release 3.0.0-beta.13 ->> GlobalSQLite secret and newsecret are deprecated" See: https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite

Comment: this is the only usage example i found here: https://github.com/jepiqueau/angular-sqlite-app-starter/blob/master/src/app/testencryption/testencryption.page.ts